# Writting cross platform kotlin 'common' modules targeting ios and android

Tags: android, ios, kotlin

I am looking at using [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) to target IOS and Android development. I know kotlin-native is very new and the details are still being ironed out.

My question is, how do I target kotlin-common? How do I write kotlin code that runs on both idiosyncratic platforms without issues?

For example, worker threads are being used with kotlin-native while kotlin-JVM uses coroutines. How do I write threaded applications that target both platforms?

EDIT------------
Downvoting without giving a reason is downright lazy and shameful. Give me the reason so I know not to make the same mistake again.

This is a legitiment question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with my own multiplatform projects and after a bit of research I found out that **kotlinx.coroutine Kotlin/Native support is simply not there yet** (cf. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/246 ).

Right now you can not use the same multithreading model in both JVM and Native, you either have to make common code that does not rely on multithreading  or make a common interface that is able to run on both Workers and Coroutine (that might be quite challenging)

The kotlinx.coroutine lead dev said that bringing basic launch/async coroutine operations is planned but no release date was provided